# Guice nested generic type binding

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am using guice for dependency injection and wrote a provider that returns  `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`. How do I bind `HashMap.class` with this provider?

I looked at [this](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) but not able to figure out how to use `TypeLiteral` for the `HashMap` value (V) in `HashMap<K,V>`. Therefore, I just replaced the `V` in `<K,V>` with Object. Currently my ugly binding looks like below which has obvious disadvantages. I have to get the object and cast it to `HashMap<String, String>`to get further values. However this works but I am looking for a better suggestion.

```
    binder().bind(new TypeLiteral<Map<String, Object>>() {}).toProvider(
(Class<? extends Provider<? extends Map<String, Object>>>) TestProvider.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type literals can have their generics specified two levels deep, or as deeply as you want to go. Try this.

```
class TestProvider implements Provider<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> {
  @Override public Map<String, Map<String, String>> get() {
    // If you had Guava, you could just call "return Maps.newHashMap();".
    // On Java 7, you can use "return new HashMap<>();".
    return new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
  }
}

class TestModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override protected void configure() {
    bind(new TypeLiteral<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {})
        .toProvider(TestProvider.class);
    // or
    bind(new TypeLiteral<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>() {})
        .toProvider(HashMapTestProvider.class);
  }
}
```

- Favor interfaces instead of implementations, and note that:

  ```
                        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>
         can be cast to     Map<String, HashMap<String, String>>  (1)
  but cannot be cast to     Map<String,     Map<String, String>>  (2)
  ```

  (1) above guarantees that it only contains HashMaps while (2) can contain any map implementation.
- You may appreciate using a Guava [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) directly. It's basically a two-key map, and can create row or column maps for you as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very nice solution (plus one)